# RemoveChild javascript, if there are no more childnodes dont throw error

Tags: javascript, html-table, removechild, child-nodes

```js
function delete(){
let k = document.getElementsByClassName('row');
for(let i=0; i<k.length; i++)
{
    if(k[i].hasChildNodes()){
        k[i].removeChild(k[i].childNodes[2]);
    } 
}
}
```

```html
<div id="table">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column">1.1</div>
        <div class="column">1.2</div>
        <div class="column">1.3</div>
        <div class="column">1.4</div>
        <div class="column">1.5</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column">2.1</div>
        <div class="column">2.2</div>
        <div class="column">2.3</div>
        <div class="column">2.4</div>
        <div class="column">2.5</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column">3.1</div>
        <div class="column">3.2</div>
        <div class="column">3.3</div>
        <div class="column">3.4</div>
        <div class="column">3.5</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column">4.1</div>
        <div class="column">4.2</div>
        <div class="column">4.3</div>
        <div class="column">4.4</div>
        <div class="column">4.5</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column">5.1</div>
        <div class="column">5.2</div>
        <div class="column">5.3</div>
        <div class="column">5.4</div>
        <div class="column">5.5</div>
    </div>

</div>

<div id="button">
    <input type="button" onclick="delete()" value="delete">
</div>
```

Hi im currently trying to delete every second column with help of the removeChild() method.
If i delte all the columns, i want to have one remaining but the console obviously shows "`Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'"` since there is no more children remaining if all got deleted.

Now the Question: How can i catch this error; is there something like `if(!k[i].hasChildNodes())` or how can i tell the if statement if there are no more childs just print('hello')

Comment: Note - `delete` is an operator in javascript - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete. Use different function name.

Answer (score 4):

It might be easier to use a direct selector to the elements you want to remove instead, with `:nth-child(2)`, and then `.remove()` all elements matching the selector:

```js
function deleteRow() {
  document.querySelectorAll('.column:nth-child(2)').forEach((child) => {
    child.remove();
  });
}
```

```html
<div id="table">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">1.1</div>
    <div class="column">1.2</div>
    <div class="column">1.3</div>
    <div class="column">1.4</div>
    <div class="column">1.5</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">2.1</div>
    <div class="column">2.2</div>
    <div class="column">2.3</div>
    <div class="column">2.4</div>
    <div class="column">2.5</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">3.1</div>
    <div class="column">3.2</div>
    <div class="column">3.3</div>
    <div class="column">3.4</div>
    <div class="column">3.5</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">4.1</div>
    <div class="column">4.2</div>
    <div class="column">4.3</div>
    <div class="column">4.4</div>
    <div class="column">4.5</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">5.1</div>
    <div class="column">5.2</div>
    <div class="column">5.3</div>
    <div class="column">5.4</div>
    <div class="column">5.5</div>
  </div>

</div>

<div id="button">
  <input type="button" onclick="deleteRow()" value="delete">
</div>
```

Comment: is there a way to do it without jquery ?

Comment: Yes, my answer uses no jquery.